# Get customer or prospects in Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to get customer or prospect using X++ and use it on a lookup.
There is a method in the `DirPartyTable` that returns what I want.

```
DirPartyTable::isCustomerOrRelation

while select * from dirPartyTable
{
       if(DirPartyTable::isCustomerOrRelation(dirPartyTable.RecId))
       {

                //Get the Name
                //info(dirPartyTable.Name);
       }
}
```

But when I build a query to the lookup I am trying to pass the `DirPartyTable::isCustomerOrRelation(dirPartyTable.RecId)` on the `addRange` of the query somehow.
Is there a way to do it or is it impossible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the source of `isCustomerOrRelation` (and `isCustomer` and `isRelation`) you see, that the method returns true if a customer or prospect exists in the current company.

Your `while select`, while correct, is inefficient, because it may have to scan a million parties to select on thousand customers or prospects present in you current company.

A more efficient, but syntactical illegal, `while select` would be:

```
while select * from dirPartyTable
   exists join custTable
   where custTable.Party == dirPartyTable.RecId
   union 
   select * from dirPartyTable
   exists join smmBusRelTable
   where smmBusRelTable.Party == dirPartyTable.RecId;
{
     info(dirPartyTable.Name);
}
```

While illegal in X++ it is possible using queries and views.

1. Make two queries (translate to appropriate properties yourself):
2. Query1:

   ```
   select * from dirPartyTable
       exists join custTable
       where custTable.Party == dirPartyTable.RecId
   ```
3. Query2:

   ```
   select * from dirPartyTable
       exists join smmBusRelTable
       where smmBusRelTable.Party == dirPartyTable.RecId;
   ```
4. Make two views (View1 and View2) based on the queries.
5. Make a union query (Query3), see how to [Combine Data Sources in a Union Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc605991.aspx), remember to specify the `UnionType` (`Union` or `UnianAll`).
6. Make a view based on the Query3, see how to [Create a View Based on a Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa558501.aspx).

Result, select all records using X++:

```
while select * from dirPartyCustOrRelationTable
{
     info(dirPartyCustOrRelationTable.Name);
}
```

Or you can use the Query3 directly to retrieve the records.

Comment: Fantastic answer. I would never think this way. :)