# Filter records in DirPartyTableListPage form

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to apply ExistsJoin with RestrictionTable to records in DirPartyTable that have InstanceRelation value = 123 and not filter the others in init method in form.

I tried this, but only records with InstanceRelationType == 123 are now in form but i need to keep other as well.

```
QueryBuildDataSource            qbdsRestriction;
QueryBuildRange                 qbr;


qbdsRestriction = dirpartyTable_ds.queryBuildDataSource().addDataSource(tableNum(RestrictionTable));            
qbr = qbdsRestriction.addRange(fieldNum(RestrictionTable, Party));
qbr.value(strFmt("((%1.Party == %2.RecId) && (%2.InstanceRelationType == 123))", qbdsRestriction.name(), dirpartyTable_ds.queryBuildDataSource().name()));
qbdsRestriction.joinMode(JoinMode::ExistsJoin);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by making a union query for form datasource containing one view that was filtered with exist join and has range of InstanceRelation field = 123 and another view with unlimited value in InstanceRelation field --- the same way it was described here [Get customer or prospects in Dynamics AX 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118100/get-customer-or-prospects-in-dynamics-ax-2012)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You're using [expressions in query ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/using-expressions-in-query-ranges), which need to be on a **string** field, I believe. I'm guessing `RestrictionTable.Party` is an **int64**. Choose some other, arbitrary string field and see if that fixes it, but you probably should **not** be using *expressions in query ranges*, and use the query object traditionally.

When I say that, I mean something similar to this:

```
QueryBuildDataSource            qbdsRestriction;
QueryBuildRange                 qbr;
    
qbr = dirpartyTable_ds.queryBuildDataSource().addRange(fieldNum(DirPartyTable, InstanceRelationType));
qbr.value(queryValue("123"));

qbdsRestriction = dirpartyTable_ds.queryBuildDataSource().addDataSource(tableNum(RestrictionTable));
// qbdsRestriction.clearLinks(); // This may be needed

// Method 1 OR
qbdsRestriction.addLink(fieldNum(DirpartyTable, RecId), fieldNum(RestrictionTable, Party));

// Method 2
// qbdsRestriction.relations(true); // Only if you have a table relation

qbdsRestriction.joinMode(JoinMode::ExistsJoin);
```

You would use `qbdsRestriction.relations(true);` if you have a table relation setup. If you have a table relation and do *not* want to use them, you would need `false`. If you do not have a table relation at all, then it's not needed and you would use `// Method 1`.

I don't have your exact data so I typed this from memory without intellisense, so you may need to tweak it and experiment.